# How to make the JSON result as selected in HTML select option on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, json

I want to get the select option value as selected on load of page through JSON.

On load based on from time and to time passed through ajax, I will filter shift timings name and id as JSON result. Everything working fine but I don't know how to make the JSON result as selected in the html select option value.

This is my select HTML:

```
<select name="shift_name<%=index%>" id="shift_name<%=index%>" class="form-control"><option value="1">Morning Shift</option>
<option value="2">Evening Shift</option>
<option value="3">Night Shift</option>
<option value="4">Full Day Shift</option>
<option value="5">Full Night Shift</option></select>
```

This is my onload function to get JSON result values for select.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var from_time = $('.from_time_<%=index%>').val();
var to_time = $('.to_time_<%=index%>').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/employees/gate_passes/get_shift_timings",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {'from_time': from_time, 'to_time':to_time },
        success: function(result){
            for(term in result){
                alert(result[term].id) #getting select option value to be selceted here
                alert(result[term].name)
                render = false;
            //$('.select option[value="2"]').prop('selected', true);
            //$('select#shift_time<%=i.index%> option[value="+result[term].id+"]').prop('selected', true);
            }
        }
    })
    });
```

I have 3 select in one page. so that based on that form index select id and name will change . In JSON result I am getting the appropriate value based on my index. but I don't know how to make it selected in the particular select option.

You can see a commented section in my JSON result, that is making the option value selected for all my 3 select inputs with select option value 2 (ie I mean all my select inputs are getting selected with Evening shift name). But my second commented line not working based on id and value.

Comment: Did you try just removing the double quotes and plus signs on `result[term].id`?

Comment: `$('#shift_name<%=index%>').val(result[term].id);`

Comment: Thank you @ Hagai Wild . This  code is working .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the double quotes for single quotes.

```
$('select#shift_time<%=i.index%> option[value='+result[term].id+']').prop('selected', true);
```

With the double quotes, you defined a string... So you where looking for an `option` with a value of `+value=result[term].id+` instead of `value="2"`.

Comment: thanks @Louys Patrice Bessette i modified ur code like this. $('select#shift_time<%=i.index%> option[value='+result[term].id+']').prop('selected', true); it is working